# Webex controlling remote Windows 7 desktops and UAC prompts

Tags: windows, uac, webex

We use Webex to remotely support users by controlling their desktops. This is becoming increasingly annoying when used to connect to remote Windows 7 desktops, as UAC prompts on the remote machine cannot be seen in the local Webex session. Is there any way around this within Webex itself ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computer Configuration/Policies/Windows Settings/Security Settings/Local Policies/Security Options
User Account Control: Switch to the secure desktop when prompting for elevation: Disabled

Comment: Thanks, that's not within Webex though.